# UMVUE of $ \theta^2 (1- \theta ) $ X is random sample from bernoulli distribution

Tags: self-study, inference, bernoulli-distribution, umvue

Let $ X_1, X_2  ..... X_n $ be a random sample from  bernoulli distribution with parameter $ \theta $ , Obtain   UMVUE of $ \theta^2 (1- \theta ) $

**MY APPROACH**

I calculated that T = $ \sum X_i $ is complete , sufficient statistic for $ \theta $ , so I thought of calculating $  E( n \bar X^2  (1 - n \bar X) ) $

Which is equal to $  E( n \bar X^2 ) - E(n \bar X^3) $
The first term can be obtained using the variance formula , but I dont know how to proceed with the second term .

I used the help of one of the question explained here ,using blackwellisation and I got

$ \frac{t(t-1)(n-t)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}$ as the overall UMVUE  , where $ t = \sum X_i $

Comment: It is the difference of the MVUEs of $\theta^2$ and $\theta^3$, and these have been discussed here before. Please search the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UMVUE for Bernoulli](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348511/umvue-for-bernoulli)

Comment: @Xi'an yes , I took help of the same question to reach my answer , but I am not sure if my answer is correct , I just needed to confirm that once .

Comment: Since this is a self-study question, you need to provide more details on how you got this estimator by Rao-Blackwellisation since RB is enough of an argument for UMVUEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is how to find the expectation of $n\bar X^{k}$ (for $k=3$) when $\bar X$ is the mean of $n$ independent identically distributed Bernoulli variables.

Unless you are familiar with properties of binomial coefficients and adept at algebra, **perhaps the easiest way to obtain this goes through the probability generating function.**  A convenient starting point for this analysis notes that $Y = n\bar X = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ has a Binomial distribution with parameters $(n,\theta).$  That suggests expressing $n\bar X^{k}$ in terms of $Y.$ Simple algebra tells us

$$n\bar X^k = n^{1-k} (n\bar X)^k = n^{1-k}Y^k.$$

Thus, recognizing that the constant $n^{1-k}$ will factor out of the expectation, we have reduced the problem to finding the $k^\text{th}$ moment of $Y.$

The probability generating function of $Y$ is given, by definition, as

$$\begin{aligned}
p_Y(t) = \sum_{y=0}^n \Pr(Y=y) t^y = \sum_{y=0}^n \binom{n}{y} (1-\theta)^y \theta^y\, t^y = \left(1-\theta + \theta t\right)^n.
\end{aligned}\tag{*}$$

The last equality is an application of the Binomial Theorem.

Let $D$ be the differential operator for $t$ and observe that

$$(tD) p_Y(t) = \sum_{y=0}^n \Pr(Y=y)\, tD(t^y) = \sum_{y=0}^n \Pr(Y=y)\, yt^y.$$

Iterating this $k$ times tells us

$$(tD)^kp_Y(t) = \sum_{y=0}^n \Pr(Y=y)\, y^k t^y.$$

If, after performing this computation, we set $t=1,$ we obtain

$$(tD)^k p_Y(t)\bigg|_{t=0} = \sum_{y=0}^n \Pr(Y=y)\, y^k = E\left[Y^k\right],$$

according to the definition of expectation.  Computing these derivatives using the expression in $(*)$ tells us

> $$E\left[Y^k\right] = (tD)^k (1-\theta+\theta t)^n\,\bigg|_{t=1}.$$

Exploit this by computing successive derivatives using the sum, product, and chain rules.  As a shorthand, let $f(t) = (1-\theta + \theta t):$

$$\begin{aligned}
(tD)^1 (1-\theta+\theta t)^n &= t D(1-\theta+\theta t)^n = nt\theta(1-\theta+\theta t)^{n-1} = n\theta tf(t)^{n-1}; \\
(tD)^2 (1-\theta+\theta t)^n &= (tD) \left(n \theta t f(t)^{n-1}\right) = n t \theta f(t)^{n-1} + n(n-1)t^2\theta^2 f(t)^{n-2}; \\
(tD)^3 (1-\theta+\theta t)^n &= \cdots = n t \theta f(t)^{n-1} + 3n(n-1)t^2\theta^2 f(t)^{n-2} + n(n-1)(n-2)t^3\theta^3 f(t)^{n-3}.
\end{aligned}$$

Plugging in $t=1$ gives

$$\begin{aligned}
E[Y] &= n\theta;\\E[Y^2] &= n\theta + n(n-1)\theta^2\\ E[Y^3] &= n\theta + 3n(n-1)\theta^2 + n(n-1)(n-2)\theta^3.\end{aligned}$$

Don't forget to multiply these by $n^{1-k}$ when computing the expectation of $n\bar X^k.$  It might be worth checking your work by computing the expectations for $k=1$ and $k=2,$ which you already know.

To appreciate how general and practical this approach is, here is an `R` function to compute these moments.

```R
#
# Compute the Binomial(n, theta) moments for k = 0, 1, ..., k.max.
# Requires that `n` and `k.max` be natural numbers and it makes sense
# only for 0 <= theta <= 1 (but will work for any `theta`).
#
moments <- function(n, theta, k.max) {
  #
  # Apply tD to a polynomial a[1] + a[2]*t + a[3]*t^2 + ... + a[n]*t^(n-1).
  # The result is 0*a[1] + 1*a[2]*t + 2*a[3]*t^2 + ... + (n-1)*a[n]*t^{n-1},
  # whose coefficients are the component wise product of `a` and 0:(n-1).
  #
  tD <- function(a) a * (seq_along(a) - 1)
  #
  # Evaluate the probability generating function and its derivatives
  # iteratively.
  #
  i <- seq_len(n+1) - 1                           # 0,1, ... n
  a <- choose(n, i) * theta^i * (1 - theta)^(n-i) # (1-theta+theta*t)^n
  c(1, sapply(seq_len(k.max), function(i) sum(a <<- tD(a))))
}
```