# Find UMVUE of $p^3$

Tags: probability, distributions, estimation, inference, umvue

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from $Binom(1, p)$. I'm trying to find the UMVUE of $p^3$.

Some thoughts:

1. Apparently, $\bar{X}^3$ is not the answer, although it's the MLE of $p^3$.
2. For distinct $i$, $j$, and $k$, the distribution of $X_iX_jX_k$ is $Binom(1, p^3)$, but what if $n$ is not divisible by three?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2687375/. And if the answers there are helpful you might answer this question yourself.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for the information; they are really helpful! Wasn't aware of the [Lehmann–Scheffé theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann–Scheffé_theorem). +1

Comment: @StubbornAtom Done!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/348511/119261

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this problem is a classic example of the [Lehmann–Scheffé theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687375/how-to-find-umvue-of-thetak-with-bernoulli-distribution). The theorem states

> If a statistic that is unbiased, complete and sufficient for some parameter $\theta$, then it is the UMVUE for $\theta$.

Here $\theta$ is $p^3$, and $T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient and complete statistics for $p^3$, so we simply need to construct a unbiased estimator of $p^3$ with $T$. In other words, we need to find $\phi$ such that $E(\phi(T)) = p^3$. For example, you can readily verify

$$
\phi(T) = \frac{T(T-1)(T-2)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}
$$

And that's the UMVUE of $p^3$.